# Is your answer referred from Scriptures?

Tags: discussion, sources-and-citations

I have seen many questions are requesting for an answer referred from Hindu scriptures like:

- Is it mentioned in any scriptures?
- What does scriptures say about this?

Since, Hinduism has many scriptures like Vedas, upanishads, puranas etc. I am thinking that all the answers must be referred from scriptures only.

Atleast we should try to give priority to answers from scriptures.

What do you guys think about this?

Comment: Naturally, answers to these questions must be based on the scriptures. But how can we insist the same rule to all  other questions? Giving priority is a good option.

Comment: `But how can we insist the same rule to all other questions?` keeping some kind of rule which is ok to all.. IMO.

Answer (score 4):

***I THINK YES! WE SHOULD AND EVERYONE SHOULD DEFINITELY DO THAT.***

<sub>this is an answer, no joke.</sub>

Answer (score -2):

There could be  answers which do not require reference from scriptures (*I have no examples, but there are many answers on main site which do not have any scripture reference*). So, I am suggesting OP's to include [scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) tag whenever they are looking for answer from scriptures.

Comment: The fact that there are answers on the site which don't site scripture doesn't mean that it's good that they're not citing scripture.  I think we should definitely encourage citation of scripture.

Comment: We shouldn't only encourage people to quote scripture when there's a scripture tag; citations of scripture should be the default.  The scripture tag should be reserved for questions about scripture itself, like this one: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/54/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I agree that every answer need citation from scriptures. but I proposed this solution because there are many answers on main site which are not sourced from any scriptures. Sometimes, answers are from their knowledge or from some blog as reference. eventhough the fact that the answers are not from scriptures many users are upvoting the posts as a encouragement.

Comment: Another tag used obligatorily? No please...

Comment: I posted about this on the meta site the first day the site was up. Shog also has a great answer there. I'm traveling so unfortunately I can't libknit but you should be able to find it.